# Passing callback as parameter to callback give me error Expected 1 arguments, but got 2

Tags: typescript, react-native, function, setstate

I'm tring to pass a callback to a set state but it gives me this typescript error => Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554).
i just wanted to pass a callback to setState to update the satate of the new object when function onVideoPlayed is called . can you help me ? thank you in advance

here is my code:

```
const [videos, setVideos] = useState<Video[]>(videosList);
  const [currentLanguage, setCurrentLanguage] = useState(i18n.language);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const renderItem = ({item, index}: {item: Video; index: number}) => {
    return (
      <Pressable onPress={() => onVideoPlayed(item, index)}>
        <Card video={item} currentLanguage={currentLanguage} />;
      </Pressable>
    );
  };

  function onVideoPlayed(video: Video, index: number) {
    if (video.viewedTimes && video.viewedTimes > 0) return;
    let newVideos = videos;
    newVideos[index].viewedTimes++;
    setVideos(newVideos, () => {});  ===> "here it gives me the error"
  }


  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <FlatList
        data={videos}
        keyExtractor={item => item.title}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem(item, index)}
        numColumns={4}
        contentContainerStyle={appStyles.cardListStyle}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, renderItem expects a single argument, an _object_.

Comment: i just wanted to pass a callback with a navigation i don't undestand the error

Answer (score 0):

```
  function onVideoPlayed(video: Video, index: number) {
    if (video.viewedTimes && video.viewedTimes > 0) return;
    let newVideos = [...videos];
    newVideos[index].viewedTimes = newVideos[index].viewedTimes + 1;
    setVideos(newVideos); 
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
setVideos(state=> {
    // Changes to the state
    return state;
})
```